# what exactly happens when you call channelService.RegisterChannel(ChannelName)?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I want to know what exactly happens in the system when you call channelService.RegisterChannel(ChannelName)?
Does this service gets registered somewhere so that rest of the applications can see and call it?

Answer (score 0):

The `RegisterChannel` method calls an internal [RegisterChannelInternal](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/1285b74a46155831.html) method.

Looks like that method adds the channel to an internal list. It also calls an internal `RefreshChannelData` method that calls a private `CollectChannelDataFromChannels` method whose purpose, according to the comments, is to "Ensure that our native cross-context & cross-domain channels are registered".

That leads to `RemotingServices.RegisterWellKnownChannels`, and to an internal `CrossAppDomainChannel` class. Looks like the `CrossAppDomainChannel` class uses an "XAPPDMN" channel to communicate with remote objects across app domains.

If you want to know exactly what happens, there's a starting point. Maybe someone else knows more about it.